# c++: include path variable, then header name

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a main method where I write:

```
#include "path/to/header/header.h"
```

And I do this over and over again for each of my local project includes.

Is there a way to define a variable such that I can write:

```
#some_var = "path/to/headers/"
#include "{some_var}header.h"
```

---

For example, I don't write anything in the makefile:

```
#include "../../path/to/header.h" // <-- using a relative path
```

Now, I include the project root:

```
#include "path/to/header.h" // <-- use path relative to the project root
```

Next, I include specific directories:

```
#include "header.h" // <-- user has no clue where this is.
```

---

Best case (at the moment), I include project root, and use local paths.  Now, I have the same problem:

```
#include "pathA/header.h"
#include "pathA/header2.h"
#include "pathA/..."
#include "pathB/..."

// above turns into a mess 
// with anything other than 
// a flat source dir, 
// 
// and a flat source dir 
// is a mess to anyone 
// but the original author.
```

---

So what I am shooting for is: include project root.

Then, in a code file:

```
// pseudo-code
#something src = "src/"
#something SomeLib = "dependencies/SomeLib/"


#include "{src}MyClass.h"
#include "{SomeLib}TheirClass.h"
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a task of compiler. You can do it by Makefile or CMake.

Comment: @liliscent right, but I have a CMakeLists for the ide, a makefile for simple use by a user on a command line, etc. and I would like to just, from now on, be able to edit only one thing when I add a new header lib

Comment: The capability is there but when I tried it some ten-fifteen years ago compilers differed in their support and it was a mess. Just use an ordinary include path spec for the compiler. E.g. `cpath` with g++, and `include` with Visual C++. Or you can use `-I` and `/I` options, respectively.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf ah, ok, cool.  maybe I'll just leave it up for a while...

Comment: IIRC you can use macros in `#include` directives. But it do seem more appropriate to use the build-system to add the path to the list of paths searched by the preprocessor.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok.  It just seems like, if I add it to the makefile, then I would want to add just the project root so that the user still knows what is going on when I include something from a code file...in which case I am now no longer writing local paths (for ex: `../dir/header.h`), but I am still writing paths over and over (`dir/dir2/header.h`), and I could just have that local path at the top of the file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How can you use macros in #include for this example?

Comment: I recommend not putting paths in the source code.  If your header file moves, you'll have to change all source files that include the header file.  Instead, tell the compilers the directories to search.  A common compiler option is `-I` for adding an include path.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews ok, I have already got that.  Bottom line: it comes down to flexibility vs readability, where it is readable, etc..  Either way, it’s up to the developer, and it appears to be possible to do this.